# How to add new custom field in Customer ‘Account page and in admin area?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, custom-attributes

I know this might have been probably asked before but through out the net I dint get  a single proper working post to my problem. Hence thought of asking it myself.

I would like to create a custom field "Company" for my Customer's Account and Edit page. I would also like to see this field in the admin Area in "Manage Customers" Section along with other fields like Id, Name, Email, Group, Telephone,Country, etc.

I know the best bit would be to create a custom module but what is the exact way of doing that, such that the newly created module gets reflected both on front end (A/c register and edit pages) and backend (Admin) area.

Please I would really appreciate if some one can tel me the exact way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: company field is included in address collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the solution. Its this file which needs editing for adding an extra column in Manage Customers Grid.

app/code/core/Mage/AdminHtml/Block/Customers/Grid.php

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel(‘customer/customer_collection’)
       // …
      // ADD THIS TO THE END:
      ->joinAttribute(
      ‘billing_company’, ‘customer_address/company’, ‘default_billing’, null, ‘left’);
      // …
    }
```

And to the columns:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
       $this->addColumn(‘company’, array(
       ‘header’ => Mage::helper(‘customer’)->__(‘Company’),
       ‘index’ => ‘billing_company’));
        ...
    }
```

And if one needs to add the Company field on Customer Register and edit pages then they need to edit customer/form/register.phtml and edit.phtml files and add

```
      <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="company" id="company"       value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text" />
                    </div>
```

That's it !! Hope it helps some one!

Comment: Well does any one know if we wanna do d exact same thing by creating a custom module how can we do it? I did manage to get d column show up by creating a custom module bt my "Add new Customer" button goes off. Also the value doesn't get displayed for that column? Any suggestions?